# 404 error with user pages

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I have my user-based site set up as follows:

1. Each user has their own profile page at mydomain.com/user123
2. Behind the scenes, and unbeknownst to the user, this redirects to mydomain.com/profile.php?user=user123

If someone visits any URL like mydomain.com/randomstring, how would I ensure that the viewer does not see "mydomain.com/profile.php?user=randomstring" in instances where "randomstring" is not equal to a current username that is registered with my site, but instead they see a 404 error?

(for reference purposes, profile.php populates a pre-defined template that pulls custom variables associated with each unique username.  Therefore, if a certain username doesn't exist, going to mydomain.com/randomstring would bring up an empty page titled "randomstring's profile page.")

Comment: To be clear, I know I can run an "if" statement in php to count rows where username=randomstring and redirect from there, but how can I "invoke" a 404 error status code?

Comment: You send an appropriate HTTP header. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(/*USER_DOESN'T_EXIST*/)
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, albeit not as complete as the answer above.  With that being said, you answered first and it is correct, so I chose yours.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   check the random string with database userid 
(i suppose the id is the user id) if user id not in db 
    header("location:404.php");
```

or

let apache handle for u

in your htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
```

or in your php script

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  I chose the other answerer's answer simply because it was first and it worked, but yours is more complete.  I appreciate the response.  I may toggle the htaccess rather than use the solution below, so I appreciate it.